# How to delete rows in Excel if cells in specific column are blank using python openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am a Python beginner (and also new to Stack Overflow) and I've recently discovered openpyxl which has been a lifesaver, but I cannot solve the following issue.

I have a spreadsheet with data in columns A-I. The spreadsheet is a course-completion report which tells me if customers have completed a particular course that my company offers. If the customer has completed the course, the date of completion is listed in column "I" as "mm/dd/yyyy" format. If the customer has NOT completed the course, the cell in column "I" is blank. I would like to delete all rows where the value in column "I" is blank. I have tried the following:

```
for cell in ws['I'][1:]:
    if cell.value is None:
        ws.delete_rows()
```

This didn't throw any error messages, but it also did not work. I also tried:

```
for cell in ws['I'][1:]:
    if cell.value == None:
        ws.delete_rows()
```

Again, I am a beginner, so I may be missing something very simple. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just need to specify the row to be deleted:

```
for cell in ws['I'][1:]:
    print(cell.value)
    if cell.value == None:
        ws.delete_rows(cell.row)
```

also you have to save the changes:

```
wb.save('yourfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: So simple; yet, so important! Thank you so much for pointing this out. This worked almost perfectly. I also found that instead of "if cell.value == None:" I actually needed "if cell.value == '' " and it worked perfectly. It did take about 6 minutes to loop over roughly 5,000 rows. Is there is a faster option than a for loop? Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it's working now. It would probably be faster using pandas. Import with df=pd.read_excel(yourfile.xls); then drop the rows where column I is empty and then save using df.to_excel(yournewfile.xls).